# R: Colors in dumbell plot seem to mix in inappropriate ways

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I am trying to produce a dumbell plot in R. In this case, there are four rows, and they need to have different and specific colors each. I define the colors as part of the dataset using colorRampPalette(). Then when I produce the plot, the colors get mixed in inappropriate ways. See the image below, and in particular the legend.

[image]
As you can see, the orange is supposed to be #7570B3 according to the legend. But this is not correct. The color 7570B3 is purple ! For this reason, the colors that I had defined in the dataset are mixed in the plot. "Alt 2" sound be in orange and "Alt 3" should be in purple.

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Any help would be very appreciated.

Here is a simple version of the code:

```
table_stats_scores <- data.frame(alt=c("alt1","alt2","alt3","alt4"), 
average=c(15,20,10,5),
dumb_colors= colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(4,"Dark2"))(4),
min=c(10,15,5,0),max=c(20,25,15,10)
)
table_stats_scores # This is the dataset

table_stats_scores <- table_stats_scores[order(-
table_stats_scores$average),] # ordering 

table_stats_scores$alt <- factor(table_stats_scores$alt, 
levels = table_stats_scores$alt[order(table_stats_scores$average)])
# giving factor status to alternatives so that plot_ly() picks up on this

p <- plot_ly(table_stats_scores, x=table_stats_scores$average, color = ~ 
dumb_colors, 
y=table_stats_scores$alt,text=table_stats_scores$alt) %>%

add_segments(x = ~min, xend = ~max, y = ~alt, yend = ~alt,name = "Min-Max 
range", showlegend = FALSE, line = list(width = 4)) %>% 

add_markers(x = ~average, y = ~alt, name = "Mean", 
marker=list(size=8.5),showlegend = FALSE) %>%
add_text(textposition = "top right") %>%

layout(title = "Scores of alternatives",
xaxis = list(title = "scores"),
yaxis = list(title = "Alternatives")
)
p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes color can be an issue in plotly, because there are several ways to specify it, and the assignment order of the various elements from the dataframe can be hard to keep in sync.

The following changes were made:

- added a list of brighter colors to your dataframe because I couldn't easily visualize the `brewer.pal` colors. Better to debug with something obvious.
- changed the `color` parameter to the `alt` column, because it is really just used  only indirectly to set the color, and mostly it determines the text in the legend.
- added the colors to the `text` parameter (instead of `alt`) so I could see if it was assigning the colors correctly.
- changed the sort order to the default "ascending" on the `table_stat_scores` sort because otherwise it assigned the colors in the incorrect order (don't completely understand this - seems like there is some mysterious sorting/re-ordering going on internally)
- added a colors parameter to the `add_segments` and `add_markers` so that they set the color in the same way using the same column.

I think this gets you want you want:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)
table_stats_scores <- data.frame(alt=c("alt1","alt2","alt3","alt4"), 
                                 average=c(15,20,10,5),
                                 dumb_colors= colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(4,"Dark2"))(4),
                                 min=c(10,15,5,0),max=c(20,25,15,10)
)
table_stats_scores # This is the dataset
table_stats_scores$bright_colors <- c("#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#FF00FF")

table_stats_scores <- table_stats_scores[order(table_stats_scores$average),] # ordering 

table_stats_scores$alt <- factor(table_stats_scores$alt, 
                        levels = table_stats_scores$alt[order(table_stats_scores$average)])
# giving factor status to alternatives so that plot_ly() picks up on this

p <- plot_ly(table_stats_scores, x=~average, color = ~alt, y=~alt,text=~bright_colors) %>%

  add_segments(x = ~min, xend = ~max, y = ~alt, yend = ~alt,name = "Min-Max range", 
              colors=~bright_colors, showlegend = FALSE, line = list(width = 4)) %>% 

  add_markers(x = ~average, y = ~alt, name = "Mean", 
              marker=list(size=8.5,colors=~bright_colors),showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_text(textposition = "top right") %>%

  layout(title = "Scores of alternatives",
         xaxis = list(title = "scores"),
         yaxis = list(title = "Alternatives")
  )
p
```

yielding this:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic Mike Wise !